# Writing template with universal reference

Tags: c++, templates, forwarding-reference

I have following code:

```
template<typename...Tlist>
inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, 
splitter::splitter_class<Tlist...>& splitter) {
    splitter.accept(is);
    return is;
}
```

As you can see, this code should overload operator>> for my templated class. But I want my operator to work with both L-value and R-value as argument. When I write `splitter::splitter_class<Tlist...>& splitter` it does not accept R-value, but when I try `splitter::splitter_class<Tlist...>&& splitter` it accepts only R-value. I know there is a concept of universal reference, but I have no idea how to modify this function to accept both L-value and R-value reference. Sould you please help me?

Thank you, for your time.

Comment: Simpler to have 2 overloads here.

Comment: BTW, I have difficulty to see usage from r-value_reference...

Comment: Nitpick: The term "Universal Reference" is the one coined originally by [Scott Meyers](http://www.aristeia.com), but the C++ committee later adopted "Forwarding Reference" as the official term in the standard.

Comment: @Jarod42 so there is no way, how to write this universally and I have to write two functions?

Comment: See duplicate...